# How to backup and restore the system?

Tags: system, backup

How can I make a backup of the system and then restore it, in case of serious damage or failure? This is possible after a failed experiment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [TimeShift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) for creates system restore point.

> TimeShift for Linux is a application that provides functionality
>   similar to the *System Restore* feature in Windows and the *Time Machine*
>   tool in Mac OS. TimeShift protects your system by taking incremental
>   snapshots of the file system at regular intervals. These snapshots can
>   be restored later to bring your system to the exact state it was in at
>   the time when the snapshot was taken.

TimeShift is designed to protect system files and settings. User data such as documents, pictures and music are excluded by default.

Install:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```

---

Typically, for use doesn't require any additional settings, just click the `Backup` button for create snapshot.

[image]

---

For restore select a backup from the list and click the `Restore` button on the toolbar. After, select the system partition from the *Restore Window* that is displayed. Click the `Restore` button to continue and start the restore process.

[image]

---

You can be enabled for taking automatic snapshots of the system at regular intervals. The backup levels can be selected from the *Settings* window.

[image]

---

If you can't get into the graphics mode (eg after a failed installation of video driver), you have to use [Live USB](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium) with elementary OS or Ubuntu. After booting into the live system, run the commands in terminal to install timeshift and follow the general instructions for restore.