# How can I test the new indicators?

Tags: release-freya, testing, wingpanel

I saw the screenshots of new indicators in Daniel's Google+, how can I install them?

Screenshots:

[image: Sound Indicator]

[image: Notifications Indicator]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Install

**Attention! Be careful, this is a test version of a packages, use the virtualization or make a [backup](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/675/160) for future rollback!**

Add `ppa:elementary-os/staging` and `ppa:elementary-os/daily` and upgrade libgranite3 wingpanel and greeter packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgranite3 wingpanel pantheon-greeter -y
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Install indicator-ayatana to display third-party indicators:

```
sudo apt-get install wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

Install indicator-keyboard if you use multiple keyboard layouts:

```
sudo apt-get install wingpanel-indicator-keyboard
```

Fix indicator-network doubling:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

Find the `NoDisplay=true` and replace on `NoDisplay=false`. After save changes and exit.

Run `gnome-session-properties` in the terminal and uncheck "Network" in the opening window.

[image]

After these steps logged out and in again.

## Return

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/staging
```

Go to `System Setting` > `Applications` > `Startup` and check "Network".

[image]

After these steps logged out and in again.

Comment: Is this still working?

Answer (score 2):

if you're using the daily ppa then the above will not work unless you append the following lines to /etc/apt/preferences.d/elementary-os-patches.pref:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-elementary-os-staging
Pin-Priority: 666
```

this puts the staging ppa ahead of the daily ppa, which has a "newer" version of wingpanel.

edit: <s>unfortunately the staging version of wingpanel is not built against the daily version of libmutter and this causes apt-cache errors. hopefully the team will fix this soon.</s>

OK, this one has taken some time: today (monday 5th of october) there was an updated build of wingpanel and libwingpanel put on the staging ppa. When it updated it didn't install the updated gsettings keys but you can get them with the following terminal commands:

```
wget http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel/trunk/download/parnold1%40gmail.com-20150724215205-a7hlbqwiehfv8451/org.pantheon.desktop-20150425124559-zaqsxjmitvc8wv94-32/org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel.gschema.xml
glib-compile-schemas ./
```

this only applies to existing users, new users you create will get the correct keys by default.

Comment: there's a bug here for anybody that wants to poke the developers [https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1500705](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1500705)