# Will the new indicators be released for freya?

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

Will the new indicators contained in the staging ppa (and shown on G+) make it in freya? Or will we have to wait for the next release?

I'm not interested in testing it, I want to know if it'll be released as stable in freya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test the new indicators?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/755/how-can-i-test-the-new-indicators)

Comment: @PNG While related, I don't think this is the same question, as this one is specifically asking for release date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new indicators will most likely be available with the next elementary OS version.