# My panel icons get more than 3 minutes to load

Tags: wingpanel, icons

I'm using Fyeya 0.3.2 (I guess this is the most up to date version)

However recently I'm facing a issue with the panel icons. Including network client. Panel icons get more than 3 minutes to load. I assume this happens after an OS update which performed recently.

The delays panel appications are

clipbord, Keyboard layout switcher, spideroak client, vol, 
network, blutooth, battery

What would be the issue.

I'm a fresh developer and eager to look in to the code also. So if anyone point out me where to find the panel code. Thats also appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I got the same problem also after updating.

Comment: @Abdullah Nope. Not yet. However I'm gonna look in to deep

Answer (score 0):

If you don't this feature, you can try to uninstall Parental Controls, apparently this has [helped others](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2516/68):

```
sudo apt-get remove switchboard-plug-parental-controls
```