# elementary OS: Wingpanel and plank load very slowly at boot

Tags: release-freya, boot, wingpanel, plank

My hardware specifications include a 256 GB <s>HDD</s> SSD and 8 GB of RAM. Recently, eOS has started taking around 30 seconds to load wingpanel and plank after login screen.
I referred to [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/wingpanel-taking-a-long-time-to-load-after-update) question earlier, but couldn't find a solution. The waiting time is unbearable. The only startup application I have is [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).

Recent installs include few global node packages. Looking for a solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried disabling redshift? I too have noticed longer than normal start times and also use redshift.

Comment: Maybe your HDD is failing.Have you check the S.M.A.R.T info. Anyways I recommend you get an SSD (although it don't have one)

Comment: @SuiciDoga My previous HDD was indeed failing and had replaced it this new SSD (wrongly mentioned as HDD in the question) a week ago.
I'll still check its performance, though. Thanks.

Comment: @elmato I tried that, didn't result in any improvements.

Comment: I still can't find a solution to this problem. I would hate to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

A supposed fix is to run this command:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

I too had long boot times. I found this fix and tried it and I have not had issues with boot times since.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/143